# Find first dupe across axis based on key row

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame({0: {'key': 2, 1: 7, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 7}, 1: {'key': 3, 1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 3, 5: 6}, 2: {'key': 4, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 3}, 3: {'key': 3, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 4}, 4: {'key': 6, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 4, 5: 3}, 5: {'key': 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 3, 5: 2}, 6: {'key': 3, 1: 3, 2: 7, 3: 6, 4: 6, 5: 1}, 7: {'key': 4, 1: 2, 2: 6, 3: 3, 4: 7, 5: 2}, 8: {'key': 3, 1: 1, 2: 7, 3: 4, 4: 6, 5: 3}, 9: {'key': 6, 1: 2, 2: 6, 3: 5, 4: 3, 5: 6}})`

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
key  2  3  4  3  6  2  3  4  3  6
1    7  6  3  4  5  4  3  2  1  2
2    5  4  3  2  3  6  7  6  7  6
3    4  5  4  3  6  7  6  3  4  5
4    2  3  4  5  4  3  6  7  6  3
5    7  6  3  4  3  2  1  2  3  6
```

I need to find the columns where the index in question matches the key row going from left to right.

For example at index 1, column 6 has the same value as the key row, index 2 matches the key row at column 9 and no value before. The same logic can be applied to index 3, 4 and 5.

I only need the first instance where the index matches the key value, all values after don't matter.

Expected output

```
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   trace
key   2   3   4   3   6   2   3   4   3   6   NaN
1     7   6   3   4   5   4   3   2   1   2   6
2     5   4   3   2   3   6   7   6   7   6   9
3     4   5   4   3   6   7   6   3   4   5   2
4     2   3   4   5   4   3   6   7   6   3   0
5     7   6   3   4   3   2   1   2   3   6   5
```

I have tried many variations of [duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The question is not clear as to what is being searched. May be you need to put a few pics to show a couple of searches (index1 & index2 perhaps)

Comment: I'm not sure what was unclear but I got the answer I was looking for. Thank you anyways for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) with axis along the columns, after checking where the values in df equal (`eq`)to the key row.

```
df["trace"] = df.iloc[1:, :].eq(df.loc['key', :]).idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  trace
key  2  3  4  3  6  2  3  4  3  6    NaN
1    7  6  3  4  5  4  3  2  1  2    6.0
2    5  4  3  2  3  6  7  6  7  6    9.0
3    4  5  4  3  6  7  6  3  4  5    2.0
4    2  3  4  5  4  3  6  7  6  3    0.0
5    7  6  3  4  3  2  1  2  3  6    5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np

matching_column_indices = np.empty(len(df))
matching_column_indices[0] = np.nan

for row_index in range(1, len(df)):
    row_matching_column_indices = df.loc[row_index] == df.loc["key"] 
    matching_column_indices[row_index] = row_matching_column_indices.idxmax()

df["trace"] = matching_column_indices
```

`row_matching_column_indices.idxmax()` returns the column index of the first `True` value observed, corresponding to the first match in the columns between the row at `row_index` and `"key"`.

Resulting `df`:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  trace
key  2  3  4  3  6  2  3  4  3  6    NaN
1    7  6  3  4  5  4  3  2  1  2    6.0
2    5  4  3  2  3  6  7  6  7  6    9.0
3    4  5  4  3  6  7  6  3  4  5    2.0
4    2  3  4  5  4  3  6  7  6  3    0.0
5    7  6  3  4  3  2  1  2  3  6    5.0
```

Comment: Your solution does work but I always try to avoid `for` loops when dealing with pandas